# How to add Icons to TYPO3 bootstrap package

Tags: typo3, bootstrap-icons

tI have bootstrap_package 11 and I want to add TikTok to the social media channels. What I did so far:
In my Site Package i added the following to `constants.typoscript`:

```
page {
  theme {
    socialmedia
    enable = 1
    channels {

      facebook {
        label = Facebook
        # cat=bootstrap package: social media/165/01_facebook_url;     type=string; label=Facebook: Insert the full account url
        url = https://www.facebook.com/MY_CHANNEL
      }
      instagram {
        label = Instagram
        # cat=bootstrap package: social media/165/01_facebook_url; type=string; label=Facebook: Insert the full account url
        url = https://www.instagram.com/MY_CHANNEL
      }
      youtube {
        label = Youtube
        url = https://www.youtube.com/channel/MY_CHANNEL
      }
      tiktok {
        label = TikTok
        url = https://www.tiktok.com/@MY_CHANNEL
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Facebook, Instagram and Youtube show up in the constant editor and on the footer of my page.

After some research and a hint from the community it turns out that `bootstrap_package` is carefully optimized and includes a very small number of bootstrap icons, not including the tiktok icon.

I tried various ways to override the default icon set to no avail. Is there any decent way to add an icon to the boostrap icons set?